# AWS OpsWorks app layer: environment variables not accessible from PHP app

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I love the services AWS is offering. I'm using OpsWorks to deploy my PHP apps, but I can't access any environment variables from the PHP app, to securely connecting to the databases. Neither with `getenv` and not with `$_SERVER`.

I've found the following question about this topic: [Set environment variables with AWS Opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462827/set-environment-variables-with-aws-opsworks), but I can't imagine this is the way to go.

Can anybody tell me how I can access those environment variables?

Comment: I don't know anything about AWS, but can you outline what you didn't like about the solutions you have found? Did they not work, or were they unsuitable?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the AWS doc:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/apps-environment-vars.html

In my case i just set the environment variable to db_host

```
getenv("db_host");
```